# Facebook API - public posts of a random user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm looking into retrieving all public posts of an user from Facebook. Since Facebook has at least 2 APIs (or ways of accessing its data) as far as I know (FSQL and Graph) and always changes its APIs, I'd like to know the better way nowadays of achieving such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FQL is deprecated, you can´t use it in a new App anymore.

Afaik you can´t even get public posts of a User without a User Access Token anymore, and you need the `read_stream` permission. Keep in mind that you will most likely not get that permission approved though:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

Anyway, this would be the correct endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed

**To sum it up: You can´t get the public posts of a random user.**

Comment: so if I have an application (web) and access token, I can't get the public posts of an user (random user) via Graph? I want to get them without having the user to install or accept anything.

Comment: nope, you can´t do that. public does not necessarily mean you can grab it with the api without a user token.

Comment: is that the answer to my 1st or 2nd question?

Comment: what is your second question? - it´s the answer to your comment.

Comment: Ohh, there's one only. 1) So isn't there any way to get the public post from an user at all via API? 2) Are there any other ways to retrieve them then?

Comment: **Anyway, this would be the correct endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed** -> but it's pretty much impossible to get read_stream permission for my web (or desktop?) **test** application, isn't it?

Comment: the question to question 1 is no - but isn´t that answering question 2 already?

Comment: **but isn´t that answering question 2 already?** - maybe scraping?